# Set default/init Column for sorting in Silverlight

Tags: .net, silverlight, xaml, sorting, datagrid

I found a lot of threads with the keywords above but mostly people are asking for sorting. I am asking for sorting at initialized moment. If the form loaded, the GridView should sort by a specific column already. If possible in XAML.

The default situation now, I don't need:
[image: The current loaded situation]

The default situation I want to have when form is loaded:
[image: XAML default sorting in Silverlight]

Any idea how to do that?

```
<sdk:DataGrid x:Name="dgv" 
                          ItemsSource="{Binding}"

                          >
            <sdk:DataGrid.Resources>
                <CollectionViewSource x:Key="PrioritySorter" Source="{Binding .}">
                    <CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>
                        ????? How to sort by "Active" property ASC?
                    </CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>
                </CollectionViewSource>
            </sdk:DataGrid.Resources>

            <sdk:DataGrid.Columns >
                <sdk:DataGridTextColumn         
                    Header="N°"         
                    Binding="{Binding Id}"              
                    IsReadOnly="True"/>

            <sdk:DataGrid.Columns >
                <sdk:DataGridTextColumn         
                    Header="Priority"         
                    Binding="{Binding Priority}"  />


            <sdk:DataGrid.Columns >
                <sdk:DataGridTextColumn         
                    Header="Active"         
                    Binding="{Binding Id}"  />
```

*** SOLUTION ***

```
Private Sub Service_GetItemsCompleted(sender As Object, e As ServiceReference1.GetItemsCompletedEventArgs) Handles Service.GetItemsCompleted
    'Me.Items = e.Result
    Dim pageView As New PagedCollectionView(e.Result)
    pageView.SortDescriptions.Add(New SortDescription("Rights", ListSortDirection.Ascending))
    Me.dgv1.DataContext = pageView
End Sub
```

Comment: Here is the link to get the solution for what you are looking for. [Default sorting in dataGrid in Silverlight/WPF](http://web.archive.org/web/20130605213713/http://www.exploresilverlight.com/2012/08/default-sorting-in-datagrid-in.html)

Comment: Hi vanod8812 thanks for your answer. I have a Silverlight WCF service and objects ar bound to the datagridview. I do not do anything in codebehind really. Is there any solution in XAML?

Comment: I am not asking you to do in Code behind you can do the same thing in the ViewModel and Bind the PagedViewCollection as ItemSource of DataGrid let me know if it makes sense

Comment: Here's the sample I you can provide any solution perhaps: https://skydrive.live.com/redir?resid=AD9FE0A4134005AA!2415

Comment: I just modified your code and its working as expected check this          https://www.dropbox.com/s/7i77o1pgbof15i1/DataGrid%20Sort%20Example.zip

Comment: hey comeone.... I read the whole stuff and the solution are only 4 lines of code. :-) Thanks a lot that you've taken the time to show how it works. Really simple but huge stuff to read. With your sample it's easy to understand. GREAT!!

Comment: glad that I could solve your issue cheers!!